# Zend Framework 2 adicionar assets de modo simples

Tags: zend

Boa tarde pessoal, trabalho com Zend há muito tempo e estou estruturando um projeto com o Zend 2. Acabei de descobrir que para adicionar um simples arquivo css fora da pasta public/css eu tenho que instalar um módulo inteiro e estou simplesmente perplexo. É sério isso?
Existe outra forma de fazer isso sem essa gambeta master?

http://www.razko.nl/blog/2013/01/21/managing-assets-in-zend-framework-2/

Neste link tenho 3 soluções e não achei nenhuma delas viável, que me dizem?
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Zend indica a usar uma [estrutura de diretório](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.intro.html) onde cada módulo tem a sua pasta `public` com os assets, mas **ele não resolve como disponibilizar esses arquivos**.

Você pode simplesmente jogar os seus assets  dentro da pasta public do servidor e ser feliz se não quiser seguir essa estrutura.

Caso isso não esteja funcionando, você tem que mudar alguma coisa no seu *.htaccess, segundo o código que vem no [skeleton](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) esse é o comportamento padrão, veja o código no link https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/.htaccess .

Se quiser deixar o `public` dentro do módulo, recomendo instalar o asset manager do seu link. Não é algo complicado, é só declarar no composer.json e dar um `php composer.phar update`, depois disso é fazer as configurações descritas no link que você passou.

Comment: Boa noite.
Depois de pesquisar bastante eu acabei colocando um asset manager e tudo funcionou muito bem... Acho que foi mais o susto de ver a coisa mudando tao drasticamente mesmo... khaskhhkas

Muito Obrigado.